# Alfresco upgraded to 5.1 giving 404 when browsing share items with spaces in their names

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Upgraded from 5.0.d to 5.1. Now, browsing in share, whenever I open a folder (either in document library or Repository) that has a space in the folder name, I get a 404 error.

For example, Repository->Data Dictionary uses URL:
`http://example.com/share/service/components/documentlibrary/data/doclist/all/node/alfresco/user/home/Data%20Dictionary?filter=path&size=50&pos=1&sortAsc=true&sortField=cm%3Aname&libraryRoot=alfresco%3A%2F%2Fcompany%2Fhome&view=browse&noCache=1474355274193`

to retrieve data, which on 5.0.d works fine, but 404s on 5.1. Nothing obviously related in the alfresco.log, catalina.log, etc.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

`http://example.com/share/service/components/documentlibrary/data/doclist/all/node/alfresco/user/home/Data%20Dictionary?filter=path&size=50&pos=1&sortAsc=true&sortField=cm%3Aname&libraryRoot=alfresco%3A%2F%2Fcompany%2Fhome&view=browse&noCache=1474494614509`

is not working, while

`http://example.com/share/service/components/documentlibrary/data/doclist/all/node/alfresco/user/home/Shared?filter=path&size=50&pos=1&sortAsc=true&sortField=cm%3Aname&libraryRoot=alfresco%3A%2F%2Fcompany%2Fhome&view=browse&noCache=1474494617102`

does. So it is specifically the space character that seems to matter. Same behaviour throughout (including in document library) -- space in name, link breaks, otherwise it works.

Comment: On further testing, looks like this happens also for a NEW (empty) instance of Alfresco, launched using the Bitnami AWS EC2 marketplace image, no customisation done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug on tomcat 7.0.70. So I would check the tomcat version to begin with.

Comment: Thanks - version Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 unfortunately. BUT maybe points to related (?) issue here: http://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XWIKI-13556. So maybe it is indeed a Tomcat issue. Bizarre that no-one seems to be reporting this (or my google skills are lacking)

Comment: Well thats not a supported version of tomcat for Alfresco...I would downgrade to a working version 7...

Comment: So bizarre -- this is a straight installation of the current (as of writing) Bitnami Alfresco installer (https://bitnami.com/stack/alfresco). So can it really be that out of the box it doesn't work?? Poor job Alfresco... Thanks

Comment: Um, Alfresco has nothing to do with the Bitnami installers. Maybe you meant poor job Bitnami. You might be better off just using the Alfresco installer.

Comment: Yes, quite right, I meant poor job Bitnami. Alfresco's installer presumably works great!

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct URL which I've confirmed by hitting my own 5.1 (201604-GA) server on localhost:

```
http://localhost:8080/share/service/components/documentlibrary/data/doclist/all/node/alfresco/user/home/Data%20Dictionary?filter=path&size=50&pos=1&sortAsc=true&sortField=cm%3Aname&libraryRoot=alfresco%3A%2F%2Fcompany%2Fhome&view=browse&noCache=1474409019751
```

Because you are seeing a 404 (not found) rather than a 401 (not authorized) or a 500 (problem on the server side), I suspect you are incorrectly specifying the host or port or both.

Or, if Share is coming up correctly but it cannot talk to Alfresco, check $ALFRESCO_HOME/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties to make sure alfresco.host, alfresco.port, share.host, and share.port are set correctly.

Comment: See clarification in question - space character really vital

Comment: My URL, which works, matches the URL that you say does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: And that is exactly the question! I don't know why it's not working either. But is starting to seem that the comment thread on the other answer is right, that it is a Tomcat version issue. Thanks for confirming that the URLs at least are indeed right